# Map SFMTA AVL GPS lat long to routes

Tags: data.gov, transportation, city, public-transport

SFMTA has historical AVL GPS data for their buses at ftp://avl-data.sfmta.com/avl_data/avl_raw. In each record, there is a train_assignment, which you should be able to link to the route information, however, I am unable to find a match.

from the readme file (ftp://avl-data.sfmta.com/avl_data/avl_raw/read_me.txt)

> Linking Data to the SFMTA Schedule:   To link the raw AVL data to a
>   schedule you will need to use (1) the GTFS data at -->
>   http://www.sfmta.com/cms/asite/labsindx.htm, (2) file
>   "lookUpSignUpPeriods.csv" and (3) file
>   "lookUpBlockIDToBlockNumNam.csv".     File
>   "lookUpBlockIDToBlockNumNam.csv" will allow you to link the
>   block/train numbers in field "TRAIN_ASSIGNMENT" to field "block_id" in
>   file "trips.txt" of the GTFS dataset.     File "lookUpSignUpPeriods.csv"
>   gives the dates for which each signup ID is valid.

The GTFS transit data is now found at http://archives.sfmta.com/transitdata/google_transit.zip.